# Prove that $ \left. \frac{d}{dt} \phi^{X^*}_t \omega \right|_{t=s} = \phi^{X^*}_s (L_X \omega)$, for Lie derivative acting on a one-form

Tags: differential-geometry

Lie derivative of a one-form is defined as
$$
L_X \omega (p)= \left. \frac{d}{dt} \phi^{X^*}_t \omega \right|_{t=0}(p) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}[\phi^{X^*}_{\epsilon} \omega(\phi^{X}_{\epsilon}(p)) - \omega(p) ]
$$
That is the rate of change as one drags $\omega$ along the flow of the vector field $X$, $\phi^{X^*}_t$

How to prove that,
$$
\left. \frac{d}{dt} \phi^{X^*}_t \omega \right|_{t=s} = \phi^{X^*}_s (L_X \omega)
$$.

I have tried to prove this in the following way
\begin{align}
&\left. \frac{d}{dt} \phi^{X^*}_t \omega \right|_{t=s} \\
\implies &\left. \frac{d}{du} \phi^{X^*}_{u+s} \omega \right|_{u=0} \quad(\text{substituting }t=u+s) \\
\implies &\left. \frac{d}{du} (\phi^{X}_{u}\circ \phi^{X}_{s})^* \omega \right|_{u=0} 
\quad(\text{Using } \phi_{u+s}^X= \phi_u^X \circ \phi_s^X) \\
\implies &\left. \frac{d}{du} \phi^{X^*}_{s} \circ \phi^{X^*}_{u}  \omega \right|_{u=0} 
\quad(\text{Using functorial property } (\phi^{X}_{u}\circ \phi^{X}_{s})^* = \phi^{X^*}_{s} \circ \phi^{X^*}_{u} )
\end{align}
Now, I don't know any propeties of the pull back that allows me to bring the $\phi^{X^*}_s$ out from the derivative,

I think I need to use this property,
$$
\left< \phi^{X^*}_t \omega, X \right>_p = \left<  \omega, \phi^{X}_{t_*} X \right>_{\phi^X_t(p)}
$$

How to complete the proof?

I am reading

*Isham, Chris J.*, Modern differential geometry for physicists., World Scientific Lecture Notes in Physics. 61. Singapore: World Scientific. xiii, 289 p. (1999). [ZBL0931.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0931.53002).

This problem is given on page 131.

Comment: What book/notes are you using?

Comment: @magma I've added the reference

Comment: Thank you for the reference